# Puppeteer setting the value of an nth input

Tags: puppeteer

I have an array of input boxes where I need to set the value.  The ids change so I cannot use that to get the specific inputs.  How do I set the value of each input?

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Get all the sliders
const sliders = await page.$$('input.sp-slider');

slider[0]
```

Comment: Its hard to asnwer this without seeing the structure of the HTML... You could use the container div (or whatever it is) that contains the inputs and then call that containers children to get the values. But again, we need to know the structure of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if this worked or not.

```
const values = [
    'John Doe',
    'Chicago',
    'Sesame Street'
    '+1234567890'
    'john.doe@gmail.com'
]

const sliders = await page.$$('input.sp-slider')

for (let num in sliders) {

    await sliders[num].type(values[num], {delay: 100})
    await page.waitFor (500)

}
```